# redirect page with dynamic segments

Tags: php, html, redirect

How to redirect from one page to another? Oh and my segments are dynamic, so it will change.

Is this possible?

Example.

```
www.test.com/oldtest/hello
```

to

```
www.test.com/newtest/hello
```

OR

```
www.test.com/oldtest/hellobaby
```

to

```
www.test.com/newtest/hellobaby
```

Comment: Can you show some code of how you are doing it now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a redirect to the new URL and use your segment as a variable.

```
<?php header("Location: www.test.com/newtest/" . $sSegment); ?>
```

Comment: So simple, thanks :) I will accept your answear :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

There are 2 methods to do this.

```
1. Using PHP

    <?php header("Location: www.test.com/newtest/hellobaby"); ?>

Use this as a first line in the page.

2. Using javascript

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href = "www.test.com/newtest/hellobaby";
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

write your htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/oldtest/hello  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   /newtest/hello   [R=301,L]
```